# Javascript - window.open() not opening in new tab

Tags: javascript, java, tabs, html5-video

I'm having a problem. I want to open a video in a new tab instead of the browser automatically downloading it.

```
public static native JavaScriptObject openVideo(String fileUrl)
    /*-{
           $wnd.open(fileUrl, "_blank")
           $wnd.document.body.innerHTML = "<html><body><video width='90%' height='90%' controls><source src="+ fileUrl +" type='video/mp4'>Your browser does not support the video tag.</video></body></html>";
           return $wnd;
    }-*/;
```

This opens the video in the same tab that I currently am and also opens and closes really fast another tab that downloads the video

This used to work correctly. A new tab was opened with the video player and no download started

What am I doing wrong?

What I want is for another tab to open where the video can be played and no download to occur

The videos are in a local database and have a corresponding URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys I've found the answer myself.
The problem was adding an URL in the `open()` method:

```
var newTab = $wnd.open("", "_blank");
newTab.document.body.innerHTML = "<html><body><video width='100%' height='100%' controls><source src="+ fileUrl +" type='video/mp4'><source src="+ fileUrl +" type='video/ogg'><source src="+ fileUrl +" type='video/webm'>Your browser does not support the video tag.</video></body></html>";
return newTab;
```